# Regex to remove white space between tags in gsub R

Tags: r, gsub

How to remove white space or tabulation between tags, without removing it from inside the tags, i tried gsub but didn't succeed

```
gsub("(^>)\\s(^<)", "", x)
```

Given a string like :

```
 "<div class=\"panel\">\n   <div class=\"shortcode\">\n\t    <div class=\"article-\"> text text text text </div> \n    </div>\n    </div>"
```

Desired output:

```
<div class=\"panel\"><div class=\"shortcode\"><div class=\"article-\"> text text text text </div></div></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using a [look around](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

```
gsub("(?<=\\>)(\\s*)(?=\\<)", "", x, perl = TRUE)
## [1] "<div class=\"panel\"><div class=\"shortcode\"><div class=\"article-\"> text text text text </div></div></div>"
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use the fact that the tags have `\n` between them giving particularly simple solutions:

**1)** If `s` is the input string then:

```
gsub("\\s*\n\\s*", "", s)
```

(If `\t` cannot appear within tags as is the case in the question then the pattern could alternately be written as  `" *[\n\t] *"`.)

**2)** Another way is:

```
paste(sapply(strsplit(s, "\n"), trimws), collapse = "")
```